# How to make a JFrame show advanced options when a button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want my window to expand and show more options if the user clicks a button. How can I accomplish this? I've tried adding elements to the JPanel that is on the JFrame in the actionListener of the button, but this doesn't work. I've also tried creating them before hand, and then setting them to be visible once the button is clicked, but this also doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the sample code for the cases you have done. Then we would be able to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I deleted the code since it doesn't work. I tried what I listed above (adding elements to the JPanel once the button is clicked, or setting them visible once the button is clicked), but I don't think my approach is correct.

Comment: If I were you I would do one of the following: 1. Go for using `JSplitPane` and use its `splitter` to hide the panel of advanced options. Then when the button is clicked, you can set a new position that shows the panel of advanced options. Also you may want to resize the Frame in which the panel located.   2. Re-write and provide those deleted codes.   Either ways, if you don't provide any code here, nobody can help you with the problem. It is a rule in this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is hide/display some swing objects based on a button press the following code should provide you with a basic template.

1. Create all the items you will need in the initialize method -- but make the objects that will be manipulated private to your class.
2. I prefer to have my class implement the actionlistener -- you may have a unique actionlistener for each button.
3. Have the button make the items visible on the key Press.

the basic code is:

```
package expand;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Expand implements ActionListener{

private JFrame frmBasic;
private JPanel panel;
private JButton btnShowMore,
                btnHide;
private JLabel lblAdv;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Expand window = new Expand();
                window.frmBasic.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Expand() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmBasic = new JFrame();
    frmBasic.setTitle("Basic");
    frmBasic.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frmBasic.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    frmBasic.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    btnShowMore = new JButton("Show More");
    btnShowMore.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btnShowMore, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    btnHide = new JButton("Hide");
    btnHide.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btnHide, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Basic user information");
    panel.add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    lblAdv = new JLabel("A new item");
    lblAdv.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblAdv.setVisible(false);
    lblAdv.setEnabled(false);
    lblAdv.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    panel.add(lblAdv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(btnShowMore)){
        lblAdv.setVisible(true);

    }else if(event.getSource().equals(btnHide)){
        lblAdv.setVisible(false);

    }
    frmBasic.repaint();
}

}
```

Comment: Ah, I think `repaint` was the crucial part I was missing. Will and confirm this in the morning and accept answer